# How can I change the color of the clicked button in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a simple calculator and I want to change the buttons background color when it's clicked. I want to have the code in the handleClick function, I commented the place where I want to change the color at in the code below. The index returns either +,-,* or / depending on which button you click and when it's clicked it automatically calculates the given values and changes the button color.

This is my code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
<!-- REACT -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body {
        width: 400px;
        margin: auto
    }

    .box {
        border: 1px dashed #000;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #adbed8;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
        width: 200px;
    }

    button {
        background-color: #069;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        border: none;
    }
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
<h3>Calculator</h3>
<div id="ratkaisu" class="box"></div>

<script type="text/babel">


    class Nelilaskin extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     }

     handleClick (index) {
       var myElements = document.querySelectorAll("button");
       // All buttons are color #069
       for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
           myElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#069";
       }
       // Calculate the values
       this.refs.n3.value = eval(this.refs.n1.value + index + this.refs.n2.value);
       // I want to change the color here
     }

   render() {
       return (
         <div>
       <table>
       <tbody>
       <tr><td>Luku1:</td><td><input type="text" ref="n1" /></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Luku2:</td><td><input type="text" ref="n2" /></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Tulos:</td><td><input type="text" ref="n3" /></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Laske</td><td>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "+")}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "-")}>-</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "*")}>*</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "/")}>/</button>
                  </td></tr>
       </tbody>
       </table>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }

   ReactDOM.render(
     <Nelilaskin />,
     document.getElementById('ratkaisu')
   );

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a property in state; set the button type as the property value on click; conditionally render a class name around that property for each button.

```js
class Nelilaskin extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      active: ''
    }
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    if (!this.refs.n1.value || !this.refs.n2.value) return;

    // Calculate the values
    this.refs.n3.value = eval(this.refs.n1.value + index + this.refs.n2.value);
    // I want to change the color here
    this.setState({
      active: index
    })
  }

  setActive(id) {

  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      table >
      <
      tbody >
      <
      tr > < td > Luku1: < /td><td><input type="text" ref="n1" / > < /td></tr >
      <
      tr > < td > Luku2: < /td><td><input type="text" ref="n2" / > < /td></tr >
      <
      tr > < td > Tulos: < /td><td><input type="text" ref="n3" / > < /td></tr >
      <
      tr > < td > Laske < /td><td> <
      button className = {
        "+" === this.state.active ? "active" : ""
      }
      onClick = {
        this.handleClick.bind(this, "+")
      } > + < /button> <
      button className = {
        "-" === this.state.active ? "active" : ""
      }
      onClick = {
        this.handleClick.bind(this, "-")
      } > - < /button> <
      button className = {
        "*" === this.state.active ? "active" : ""
      }
      onClick = {
        this.handleClick.bind(this, "*")
      } > * < /button> <
      button className = {
        "/" === this.state.active ? "active" : ""
      }
      onClick = {
        this.handleClick.bind(this, "/")
      } > /</button >
      <
      /td></tr >
      <
      /tbody> < /
      table > <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Nelilaskin / > ,
  document.getElementById('ratkaisu')
);
```

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto
}

.box {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #adbed8;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
}

button {
  background-color: #069;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<h3>Calculator</h3>
<div id="ratkaisu" class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could just add event to my handleClick() function like so-> handleClick(index,event) and afterwards change the color for the button like so: event.target.style.backgroundColor = "orangered";